# TextBox.text not working when convert to pdf or excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, pdf, itext

I have create a table with header. Code as below

```
HeaderCell = new TableCell();
HeaderCell.Text = "NBV <br/>" + TextBox1.Text;
HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
HeaderCell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Bottom;
HeaderCell.RowSpan = 3;
HeaderCell.Width = 60;
HeaderRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
```

When I view at webpage it is like this :

[image: column header with date]

However, when I convert to PDF or Excel it became like this :

[image: column header without date]

Can anyone tell me why it will become like this. Search google no answer found yet.
I think the problem is with the .text. When i try textbox1.toString() it able to show System.Web.UI........ in the pdf.

Comment: Try replacing the <br /> tag with \n. Maybe it works better when not using html.

Comment: \n is not working. i try before then only i change to use br tag

Comment: Ok. Check if pdf doesn't allow multiple rows of text in that cell.

Comment: That cell is allow multiple row of text. I try before that cell can show multiple line of text

Comment: just guessing, but it may require `Environment.NewLine`? never heard that html tags would be interpreted from Cell.Text

Comment: Just now tried. Still same nothing show up

Answer (score 0):

Can u try to replace br tag to Environment.NewLine like this

```
HeaderCell.Text = "NBV" + Environment.NewLine + TextBox1.Text;
```